# Unable to create ADF Linked Service for Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL Cluster

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-postgresql, linked-service

I am facing issue when creating a linked service from ADF for Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSql CLuster.. Please help me to resolve the issue.

**Note:**

- Cluster is running.
- In the cluster in Networking 'Public Access'[Public endpoint] is enabled.
- The cosmos DB for PostgresSQL CLuster and ADF both are in same subscription, region and same resource group.
- I have given right db access password as I am able to connect the cluster from PgAdmin tool

But I am getting error as below..

[image: Linked service using details from Azure Subscription]

**I have tried to enter Manually too, But different error.**

[image: Linked service using details from Manual entry]

I have tried to create a private endpoint to access but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL Cluster with ADF, but there is no option to select it. This may be the reason for the error below:

```
The value of the property '' is invalid: 'The remote name could not be resolved: 'c.cluster6391.postgres.database.azure.com''.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'c.cluster6391.postgres.database.azure.com'
```

To resolve this, select `Azure Database for PostgreSQL` and enter the details manually instead of using the subscription method.

The following error occurs when selecting **`No encryption`** as the Encryption method during the creation of the Linked Service:

> 28000: No pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxxxx", user "citus", database "citus"; no encryption. Check the network connectivity settings of your Azure PostgreSQL Flexible Server. If Private Access (VNet integration) is selected, please use SHIR to connect.

To fix this issue, choose **`SSL`** for the `Encryption method` and test the connection, as shown below:

[image]